# How do I set the image when pulling data from another data file in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

Actually, I prepared this data and koala.png does not show up. But the other picture I took from the website looks. how can I fix this?

```js
    export default [
        {
            "unit": "Letters",
            "a": 0,
            "picture": "../src/img/koala.png",
        },
        {
            "unit": "Numbers",
            "a": 1
        "picture": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/1.jpg",
        },

    ];
```

Comment: https://reactnative.dev/docs/images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this way if the local image

```
 export default [
        {
            "unit": "Letters",
            "a": 0,
            "picture": require(‘./assets/images/photo1.jpg’), // like this
        },
        {
            "unit": "Numbers",
            "a": 1
        "picture": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/1.jpg",
        },

];

<Image source={item.picture} />
```

Comment: How can I write it in the data file? {
            "unit": "Letters",
            "a": 0,
            "picture": "../src/img/koala.png",
        },

Comment: @selcukctn updated my answer please check